# add two new replacement fiends after the variables formatted string (Python)

Tags: python, formatting, syntax-error

I dont understand what I am suppose to do here. I am in Computer Science II and my assignment was to take this code here:

```
flowers = "{f[1]}: {n[1]}".format(
    f=["daisy", "rose", "tulip"],
    n=[3, 5, 2])

print(flowers)
print(len(flowers))
print(flowers.capitalize())
```

With this output:

```
rose: 5 
7
Rose: 5
```

and add 2 replacement fields and use \n escape and some more print functions to create this output

```
Flower Inventory
rose: 5
daisy: 2
tulip: 3
```

But I keep getting syntax errors and unexpected character continuation errors

Comment: Where is your try?...Need to see it to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
flowers = "{f[1]}: {n[1]}".format(
f=["daisy", "rose", "tulip"],
n=[3, 5, 2])

print('Flower Inventory')
print('\n')

for flower in flowers 
   print flower + '\n'
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question (this answer was in the Low Quality Posts review queue).